# B-movie about evil praying mantis aliens that attacked Earth

Tags: story-identification, b-movies

There’s this really terrible movie and I loved it.

There were these evil praying mantis aliens that attacked Earth. And one at the military place bit off a guy’s head. And you see a tube with blood squirting out. And people are hiding behind a fence, watching, but the camera doesn’t hide it well enough that there’s not enough fence so it’s just one panel.

It’s in color, so it’s not the 50s movie I looked up. It played on the old Sci-Fi channel that played really bad B movies. And I’ve always wanted to watch it again.

Comment: (1) Approximately when did you see this movie?  (2) Where were you at the time (what country)?  (3) Was it in English?  (4) Is it possible that the version you saw was dubbed (or had subtitles)?  Do you know what language (and/or what country) it was made in?  (5) Do you remember any characters in the movie?  Any dialog?  (6) You mention “the 50s movie I looked up”.  What is that?  If you’ve identified a movie that is similar to the one you’re looking for, but you’ve ruled it put, tell us, so people won’t waste your time (and theirs) by suggesting that one.   … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … See also [our guidance](//scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/30482) on asking good story-ID questions.

Comment: The Deadly Mantis (1957) is what springs to mind; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uSJgoaDJ1cA

Answer (score 4):

"Alien Apocalypse" (2005 TV movie)

It sounds similar to this movie that was shown on the old Sci-Fi channel and had aliens that looked like praying mantises. The scene with an alien biting off the head of a human occurs at about 1:42 of the trailer/clip video from YouTube posted below.

Comment: My word, that's some amazing CGI

Comment: @Valorum. And yet the op said it was a 'really terrible movie' so this must not be it.

Comment: Even if its bad, it earns points because of Bruce.